# Creating a list of conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, indexing

I am trying to create a list of conditions using `Table[]` in the following way:

```
Range[100]/.Table[t_ /; t > k && Mod[t, k] == 0 -> "",{k,2,10}]
```

but the result does not change the index value k from 2 to 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inject table iterator values into held expressions with `With`:

```
Range[100] /. 
 Table[With[{k = k}, t_ /; t > k && Mod[t, k] == 0 -> ""], {k, 2, 10}]
(*
{1, 2, 3, "", 5, "", 7, "", "", "", 11, "", 13, "", "", "", 17, "", \
19, "", "", "", 23, "", "", "", "", "", 29, "", 31, "", "", "", "", \
"", 37, "", "", "", 41, "", 43, "", "", "", 47, "", "", "", "", "", \
53, "", "", "", "", "", 59, "", 61, "", "", "", "", "", 67, "", "", \
"", 71, "", 73, "", "", "", "", "", 79, "", "", "", 83, "", "", "", \
"", "", 89, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 97, "", "", ""}
*)
```

See "Possible Issues" in the docs for [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html#21710) (second-to-last example group).